# Why do we need two triple-DES tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request

[Triple-DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) is a cryptography algorithm for a block cipher. From the linked Wikipedia page:

> In cryptography, **Triple DES** (**3DES** or TDES), officially the Triple Data
> Encryption Algorithm (TDEA or Triple DEA), is a symmetric-key block
> cipher [...]

Now, we have the tag [tripledes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tripledes):

> Triple DES is a symmetric encryption algorithm that uses the DES
> cipher three times to encrypt each block of data. **The formal name of
> this algorithm is the Triple Data Encryption Algorithm**.

And then we have [3des](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3des):

> In cryptography, **Triple DES, or 3DES**, is the common name for the
> **Triple Data Encryption Algorithm** (TDEA or Triple DEA) block cipher,
> which applies the Data Encryption Standard (DES) cipher algorithm
> three times to each data block.

Clearly those tags mean the same thing. There are even 35 questions tagged with both...

Since I don't have enough (any) points in any of those tags I can't suggest a synonym. I am not sure about the direction, but the [3des](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3des) one has more questions and more watchers so it might as well be the *"main"*.

Comment: Someone probably deleted the third one. We need to create it again.

Comment: @yivi would that be [desdesdes] or [des*3]?

Comment: Probably for the same reason the world needs double ROT-13.